# How to use % arguments in Easy Breadcrumbs "Paths to replace with custom breadcrumbs"

Tags: 8, commerce, breadcrumbs

I am trying to give a more logical breadcrumb flow to the Drupal Commerce 2 checkout path, as Commerce doesn't support breadcrumbs in the checkout process.

When **not** displaying the current page in Easy Breadcrumb, Drupal Commerce 2 by default it gives you a trail like this **Home > Checkout** after progressing from the `/Cart` page to the `/Checkout` page. This redundantly brings you back to the checkout page that you are already on.

The logical flow here when excluding your current page from the crumb, should be **Home > Cart** when you have proceeded to the `/Checkout` page from the `/Cart` page.

This Breadcrumb can be easily set in easy breadcrumbs **Paths to replace with custom breadcrumbs** as seen in the picture:

[image]

But the problem is that the order number is placed in the URL, so you would need to replace the actual order number (5 in this example) with % argument something like `/checkout/%/order_information :: Cart|/cart`

Is it possible to somehow accept % arguments in the URL's in "Paths to replace custom breadcrumbs"?

Answer (score 1):

There is a patch here in progress to allow wild cards in breadcrumbs:

https://www.drupal.org/project/easy_breadcrumb/issues/3051106